# how to persist an onclick function after page reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage

I have an html here which executes a simple alarm  based on the input time. I'm running nodejs webserver and this is my index.html

My problem is after clicking the "set alarm" button the function initiates but of course after reloading the page everything is gone. I've read about local storage but I don't know how to implement it in this scenario. I tried using garlic.js but only works on input forms like text field and checkboxes, not a button that executes a function.

```js
var alarmSound = new Audio();
alarmSound.src = 'alarm.mp3';
var alarmTimer;

function setAlarm(button) {
  var ms = document.getElementById('alarmTime').valueAsNumber;
  if (isNaN(ms)) {
    alert('Invalid Date');
    return;
  }

  var alarm = new Date(ms);
  var alarmTime = new Date(alarm.getUTCFullYear(), alarm.getUTCMonth(), alarm.getUTCDate(), alarm.getUTCHours(), alarm.getUTCMinutes(), alarm.getUTCSeconds());

  var differenceInMs = alarmTime.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();

  if (differenceInMs < 0) {
    alert('Specified time is already passed');
    return;
  }

  alarmTimer = setTimeout(initAlarm, differenceInMs);
  button.innerText = 'Cancel Alarm';
  button.setAttribute('onclick', 'cancelAlarm(this);');
};

function cancelAlarm(button) {
  clearTimeout(alarmTimer);
  button.innerText = 'Set Alarm';
  button.setAttribute('onclick', 'setAlarm(this);')
};

function initAlarm() {
  alarmSound.play();
  document.getElementById('alarmOptions').style.display = '';
};

function stopAlarm() {
  alarmSound.pause();
  alarmSound.currentTime = 0;
  document.getElementById('alarmOptions').style.display = 'none';
  cancelAlarm(document.getElementById('alarmButton'));
};

function snooze() {
  stopAlarm();
  alarmTimer = setTimeout(initAlarm, 6000); // 5 * 60 * 100
};
```

```html
<input id="alarmTime" type="datetime-local">
<button onclick="alarmButton" id="setAlarm(this);">Set Alarm</button>

<div id="alarmOptions" style="display: none;">
  <button onclick="snooze();">Snooze 5 minutes</button>
  <button onclick="stopAlarm();">Stop Alarm</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please fix the console error. You want to use localStorage/sessionStorage

Comment: Like you allready mentioned i would make use of the localstorage. You can simply set and get string values into the storage and query them when your page is loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local storage would be a good way to keep track of the alarm time between sessions/page refreshes.

To save `alarmTime` to local storage, use:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('alarmTime', alarmTime)
```

Then when you want to use `alarmTime`, retrieve it from local storage with:

```
window.localStorage.getItem('alarmTime')
```

One thing to note is that local storage only stores strings, at least in the more popular browsers (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)), so keep that in mind here.

See MDN docs on local storage for more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

To have your function execute again after the page is refreshed, you can add a line like this:

```
document.onload = () => setAlarm(button);
```

Which will cause `setAlarm` to be called when the page finishes loading.

**Edit**

Here is a rough layout of how you can incorporate the above information into your code. I think it's actually better to store `ms` in local storage rather than `alarmTime` so that you can populate the input with `ms` from local storage when your document loads.

```
document.onload = function() {
    var ms = window.localStorage.getItem('ms');
    if (ms) {
        populateTimeInput(ms);
        var alarmButton = document.querySelector('#alarmButton');
        setAlarm(alarmButton);
    }
}

function populateTimeInput(newTime) {
    var timeInput = document.querySelector('#alarmTime');
    timeInput.value = newTime;
}

function setAlarm(button) {
    var ms = document.getElementById('alarmTime').valueAsNumber;
    if (isNaN(ms)) {
        alert('Invalid Date');
        return;
    }

    window.localStorage.setItem('ms', ms);

    // then everything else is the same
}

function cancelAlarm(button) {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    // and everything else the same
}
```

Three main things this code adds:

- When your page finishes loading, this code will check local storage for `ms`, if it finds a value for `ms`, it populates the `alarmTime` input with the value it's found and then calls `setAlarm` automatically.
- When `setAlarm` is called, save `ms` to local storage (if `ms` has a valid value).
- When `cancelAlarm` is called, clear local storage.

This is perhaps not the most elegant way to handle all of this, but I hope it at least gets you going in the right direction — keep iterating!

Comment: The alarmTime would be stored but will the function still be excecuted after page reload?

Comment: If you want a function to execute after a page reload that'll need to be handled with `document.onload` or `window.onload`. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load). Made an edit to the post

Comment: Where exactly should I put the  `document.onload` where in the code can I use the  `setItem ` and  `getItem ` function. Can I just store the set date and bring it back after page refresh and also execute a function that will click the Set Time button after page refresh?

Comment: @Onjieee made some edits, see the last section for how you might use these ideas

Comment: Thank you very much! Will try this as soon as I get home :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am using setInterval instead of setTimer and I am storing the remaining time in local storage and decreasing it by 500 after every 0.5sec.

```js
var alarmSound = new Audio();
alarmSound.src = 'alarm.mp3';
var alarmTimer;

function setAlarm(button) {
  var ms = document.getElementById('alarmTime').valueAsNumber;
  if (isNaN(ms)) {
    alert('Invalid Date');
    return;
  }
  
  var alarm = new Date(ms);
  var alarmTime = new Date(alarm.getUTCFullYear(), alarm.getUTCMonth(), alarm.getUTCDate(), alarm.getUTCHours(), alarm.getUTCMinutes(), alarm.getUTCSeconds());

  var differenceInMs = alarmTime.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();

  if (differenceInMs < 0) {
    alert('Specified time is already passed');
    return;
  }
  startTimer(differenceInMs)
  button.innerText = 'Cancel Alarm';
  button.setAttribute('onclick', 'cancelAlarm(this);');
};

function startTimer(time){
  localStorage.setItem("timeLeft",time)
  alarmTimer = setInterval(initAlarm, 500);
}

function cancelAlarm(button) {
  clearInterval(alarmTimer);
  button.innerText = 'Set Alarm';
  button.setAttribute('onclick', 'setAlarm(this);')
};

function initAlarm() {
  var timeLeft = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("timeLeft"))-500;
  if(timeLeft <= 0){
  alarmSound.play();
  document.getElementById('alarmOptions').style.display = '';
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("timeLeft",timeLeft)
  }
};

function stopAlarm() {
  alarmSound.pause();
  alarmSound.currentTime = 0;
  document.getElementById('alarmOptions').style.display = 'none';
  cancelAlarm(document.getElementById('alarmButton'));
};

function snooze() {
  stopAlarm();
  alarmTimer = startTimer(6000); // 5 * 60 * 100
};
```

```html
<input id="alarmTime" type="datetime-local">
<button onclick="alarmButton" id="setAlarm(this);">Set Alarm</button>

<div id="alarmOptions" style="display: none;">
  <button onclick="snooze();">Snooze 5 minutes</button>
  <button onclick="stopAlarm();">Stop Alarm</button>
</div>
```